# Opel Astra H CDTI 1.7 ISSUES

Tags: opel, astra

When am speeding there is a car sign with spanner that comes on the dash board. I would like to know what exactly is the fault. Thank you.

Comment: Can you find a picture of the light you are talking about? You may be able to point the light out by taking a picture of the dash when you first turn the key on, but before you actually start it. What you are describing is probably the check engine light (CEL), but would like to make sure. Also, what do you mean by "speeding"? This is a very arbitrary term. Can you please throw in what year your car is? Have you had the OBD-II codes read? Even though the light goes off, your system should store the codes.

Answer (score 1):

The car with a spanner warning light is an indication that your vehicle is due for service